# No sound (no sound HW on my account)

Tags: 16.04, sound

(I have an Ubuntu 16.04)
Sound worked great until my last restart...
Now I see nothing on "sound configuration->output", so there's nothing I can configure there...
If I add a bluetooth sound device, I can link to the device, but it's not showed up there...
... but the hardware is there before I start the session and it's also there when I start a guest session (with the guest I see the sound hardware and it works normally, but with my user, everything dessapears ...)
I updated the kernel (4.8.2) and I remove the previous one before my last restart.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Try running Ubuntu from a live disk and see if it has sound, if it does your problem is software based. If not chances are you have a hardware issue. Good luck

Comment: It's not neccesary: it already works on a guest account. It "turns off"/dissapears when I open my session... so it's not hardware, it's a configuration problem...

Comment: I can even switch from my account (where sound doesn't work) to my already open guest account, where the sound works... <br>
If I wanna ear music, I have to change to the guest account, put it on and switch back to my account. I can't change anything on the audio, but the music is still playing.<br>
I'm doing a MOOC and each time I want to see a video, I have to switch to the guest account :-(<br>
The guest sees this https://s11.postimg.org/h8vz7iqxf/Sound.png, but on my account, that "Salida" frame is empty (https://s3.postimg.org/cbo21j8hv/sound_ADL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: as soon as I renamed the '~/.config/pulse' folder to 'pulse_vErr' (open a terminal, cd .config (pwd should show ~/.config) and there, mv pulse pulse_vErr
It immediately creates a new pulse folder and the sound icon shows again the volume.
I knew it was a configuration problem, so...